# Net Core MVC - Layout method call

Tags: .net-core, configuration, global, environment

I have a bunch of environmental settings in my appsetting - directories, DB connection string etc. I'd like to call a method from the layout page (referenced by all my views as it constructs the navbar) which will return a boolean indicating if everything is accessible (i.e. it will read config, check directories exist, can connect to DB etc.). I want to do this in layout so every page will check and indicate if all environment settings are online.

Just polling here for the best practice approach. Would a new class with a method to check all environment settings which can be called from the layout razor page be an option? Or maybe I'm over complicating it by not knowing there is an easier way to do this baked into the framework. All and any feedback very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's certainly no reason why you couldn't do it in the layout if you wanted to. Alternatively you could do it from a base page class that all other pages inherit from.

But that's not a standard way. I think you should consider using the built in health monitoring in ASP .NET Core, which would expose one or more endpoints for checking connections to databases, available file storage etc.

Documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1